# How to add condition for List type in TypedQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I have entity with following attributes:

```
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
public class MyTable {
  ......
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mytable", cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<MyAnotherTable> otherTableValues = new ArrayList<MyAnotherTable>();
  ......
}
```

Now I am trying to write HSQL as

```
TypedQuery<Share> q =
            getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT MyTable FROM MyTable AS mytable WHERE " +
                    "mytable.someField=:firstParam AND mytable.secondField IS NOT NULL AND " +
                   // "AND mytable.otherTableValues"
                   , Share.class);
    q.setParameter(firstParam, firstVal);
    return q.getResultList();
```

So not sure how to put consition on otherTableValues as it is list type. Any suggestion?

Comment: what error do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to join the collection:

```
SELECT DISTINCT mytable
FROM MyTable AS mytable join mytable.otherTableValues AS otv
WHERE mytable.someField = :firstParam
  AND mytable.secondField IS NOT NULL
  AND otv.someOtherField = :someOtherField
```